# How to install visual studio in a shorter time?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have installed visual studio before on a couple of machines and installation end successfully each time, however, it takes SOOOO LONG !
Is there any way that could fasten my installation ?

Comment: Download the ISO image and then install from it. That can only save you some download time, but the installation itself is still time consuming and no way to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Visual studio ISO and disable the internet when you install Visual studio.

**Why** : In some cases Visual Studio try to download & install things like ( google chrome) and some other thing even you try to install it from Offline setup.